# Alternative to EOS Remote app for 6D?

Tags: canon, timelapse, iphone, intervalometer, apps

Has anyone found an alternative app for iPhone/iOS that supports the 6D/70D over internal Wi-Fi? I have been vastly disappointed with Canon's EOS Remote and was curious if anyone has found an alternative.

I'd like to do timelapses (I've tried magic lantern before), and the only app that seems to support this over the 6d's internal wifi that I've been able to find is qDSLRDashboard which I haven't been able to get to perform very well. Any other suggestions?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking for something allowing similar functionality of "DSLR Controller" for Android on iOS.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "internal Wi-Fi"? I would use that term to describe the fact that the antenna isn't visible or something similar. You use it to describe a technique - what do you mean?

Comment: @Hugo - He is referring to Canon WFT(Wireless File Transmitter) that is the technology built into the Canon 6D. That would be in contrast to some other wireless technology such as a Eye-Fi, CamRanger, or similar product. He used that terminology because that is how the developer of qDSLRDashboard referred to it here: http://dslrdashboard.info/qdslrdashboard-v0-1-4_beta/ "Canon 6D internal wifi works (including live view)"

Comment: @dpollitt I see. Wasn't aware of qDSLRDashboard's name of it. For a second I thought the Kevin by "internal Wi-Fi" meant the fact that the 6D has the ability to act as an access point. Now the meaning is clear to me.

Comment: Anyone else have any input?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for because I don't quite understand your question, but have you looked at Triggertrap?

http://triggertrap.com/products/apps/mobile/

Comment: Triggertrag requires a cable connection. It will not work over WiFi, which is what Kevin was looking for.

Comment: I use Triggertrap for my Canon 6D for timelapse and it works great. This option is tethered to your phone but if you need wireless you can operate with another phone on the other end which I've never tried.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is: "I want to do a time lapse photography with EOS remote or iOS app on iPhone/iPad" then the answer is: such an app doesn't exist. I have been searching for it for 2 years.

Use an intervalometer or Triggertrap kit has a iOS app which is closer since it provides specific modes for time lapse and star trails. But it doesn't work on WiFi and requires cable connection as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Cascable](https://cascable.se/) as an alternative to Canon Camera Connect, it has live shooting and *bulk* image transfer which makes it very useful.  Read the [DPReview](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/4679507757/cascable-ios-app-offers-remote-control-of-wifi-enabled-cameras).